# Max Date available in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the max value  we can give as string in 'new Date(??)', I would like to assign the input date to default max date and in that case what is the highest possible date available in javaScript.

Comment: When all else fails, [*read the specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range).

Answer (score 3):

From [Spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range):

The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is slightly smaller: exactly –100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC. This gives a range of 8,640,000,000,000,000 milliseconds to either side of 01 January, 1970 UTC.